# Multiple Conditions in SQL join, shopping cart example

Tags: sql, left-join

[Cart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvl0H.png)

I have two tables that I am working with related to a shopping cart.  The first is the product table, and then the cart table.  Note i have only included the relevant columns.  I want to pull records from the product table that have not already been added to my cart.  I can do it when there is only 1 memberid, but as you get more members, products will overlap so that is not going to work.  I need to constrain my left outer join to include the member id also.  This is what i have so far and this works.  The issue is, how do i then constrain it to not show me products from the product table that have already been added to "my" cart which means to exclude where the memberid = 5

```
SELECT top 50
product.productid
      FROM [shopping].[dbo].[product] with (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN cart with (NOLOCK) on product.productid = cart.productid
      where 1=1
      and cart.productid is null
```

My results should pull records 1 - 5 only.

I am clarifying what i want per Universus' comment.  I want the query to display records from the product table that HAVE NOT already been added to cart.  So i want the results to exclude records that are already in the cart for my memberid.  This is not for an actual shopping cart application but i thought it would be best explained this way.  I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: It is not clear what exatly you want. Could you edit your question and  create desired result example?

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve].  Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Please read & act on [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show what parts you can do, explain where you are stuck.

Comment: ... This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. Eg 'I want the query to display records from the table that HAVE NOT already been added sql stackoverlfow' immediately gives answers. Please clarify by editing your post into the best it can be, not via comments or addendums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
SELECT top 50 product.productid
  FROM [shopping].[dbo].[product]
  WHERE product.productid NOT IN (SELECT productID
                                   FROM Card
                                   WHERE MemberID = <current member ID value>
                                 ) A
```

Meaning "*show me all products that were not selected by the current member*". This is assuming that you clean the Cart table once the transaction is completed.

Comment: once the transaction is completed, the cart table has a field that switches the records in the cart table from 0 to 1 to signify the record was purchased, and thus i do not clear the cart table.  This is actually being used to purchase data records, which is why i don't clear the cart table, and why i want to exclude records in the cart table when viewing available products if that makes sense.

Comment: You can simply add a condition to the INNER select like `AND Purchase_Flag = 0`.